# View commit that will be referenced when using tilde ~ or caret ^ with HEAD?

Tags: git

Since Git operations must be done with precision, and commit histories can sometimes be complex, the use of caret and tilde can sometimes be a little precarious.

Is there a way we can see which commit will be referenced when using tilde or caret ***before*** attempting an operation in which they'll be used? Note: I'm aware of `dry-run` but I prefer something much simpler that just shows the referenced commit, if it exists.

#### Example

Suppose we have [this](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) commit history with parent commits ordered left-to-right:

```
G   H   I   J
 \ /     \ /
  D   E   F
   \  |  / \
    \ | /   |
     \|/    |
      B     C
       \   /
        \ /
         A
```

Suppose we want to reference commit F.

We could guess `HEAD^2^1` should reference commit F.

Is there a Git command to see the commit/SHA/message for `HEAD^2^1` so we can know for sure we're referencing the commit we intend to reference?

#### Desired output

I would hope to run something like this and receive back a commit that it references:

```
git <command> HEAD^2^1

commit 64ccfb82af41e92edc4118ed9736a49ffcca7679
Author: John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 20 20:52:13 2021 +1100

    Update api key usage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git show -s HEAD^2^1`

should do the job.

Doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--s) for the `-s` option to suppress diff output.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect. Out of interest, what's the difference between that and your first suggestion `rev-parse` ?

Comment: @stevec The early `rev-parse` comment was an effect of me reading too hastily :-) Then I realized you didn't just want to get the hash.

Comment: just wanted to let you know I use this almost daily now. I am not fully across all the subtle complexities of using ^ and ~ especially in complicated repos with lots of branching/merging. So the code you gave gives a lot of confidence before making changes.